# Using Gstreamer in node js?

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, webrtc, gstreamer, rtsp

Is there any node module which allow me to use Gstreamer in Javascript code running on NodeJS?

I need to read the video feeds from RTSP-enabled axis camera. I want to convert this into the video stream which I can modify later. Currently, i am using `node-rtsp-stream` but internally it uses `ffmpeg` to create video stream. Below is the code snippet for more reference:

```js
Stream = require('node-rtsp-stream');

stream = new Stream({
  streamUrl: 'rtsp://freja.hiof.no:1935/rtplive/_definst_/hessdalen02.stream',
  wsPort: 9999
})
        
master.localStream = stream;
```

I want to get this stream object by using Gstreamer in Javascript on NodeJS.

Comment: You can look at https://github.com/RSATom/wcjs-gs But it has limited API at the moment.

Comment: @RSATom are you planning on reviving the project? To catch up with the latest versions?

Comment: @JakubLicznerski I'm using it myself in production with Node.js, so it's pretty alive. If you have any issues you could open issue on GitHub.